# warning of setselected textcolor

Tags: objective-c, xcode

hello
I am getting the warning like  " setselectedtextcolor is deprecated".

Please help me why I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **setselectedtextcolor** use `highlightedTextColor` property of the `UILabel` objects assigned to the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is informing you that that particular method will not be available in future version of iOS so you should stop using it.

Comment: tell me what method I have to Use instead of that